# Listview in VBA - amouting is not pulling with format

Tags: excel, vba

The amount is not pulling in listview with proper format. Eg: If I enter 1,00,000 then listview is showing as 100000. Can you please assist me

I just want to show the commas in my amount.

Answer (score 0):

Listview controls only accept text. If you add something that's not text, it converts it however it sees fit.  If you want to format a number or date to display a certain way, you have to format it yourself.

```
lvItem.ListSubItems.Add Format$(10^6,"#,###,##0")
```

Comment: Amount column is 'B' and I want to add comman in amount column.. Below is my coding

For I = 2 To rowCount
        Set LstItem = Me.ListView1.ListItems.Add(Text:=rngData(I, 1).Value)
               For j = 2 To ColCount
            LstItem.ListSubItems.Add Text:=rngData(I, j).Value
                        ListView1.FullRowSelect = True

        Next j
    Next I

Comment: Edit your question to include what you're doing and format as code. I will edit my answer to use your names. I didn't know your names when I answered.